# Implement thread in Three-tier architectures: can't open database

Tags: c++, qt, threadpool, qsqlquery

I want to separate the Db interaction with the main thread. A connection will sub-class `QRunnable` and start open a connection in `run()` function, a connection manager will hold `QthreadPool` and start the task when a query is needed.

But the problem is it keep report can't open the database, if I use the same code in a simple `main()`, it works well. So I have no idea?

Any ideas are appreciated :)

here is my implement:

```
#include <Qt/QtSql>
#include <QRunnable>
class DbConnection : public QRunnable
{
private:
    QSqlDatabase db;
    bool isConnectToDB;
public:
    DbConnection();
    QSqlDatabase getDb() const;
    void setDb(const QSqlDatabase &value);
    bool getIsConnectToDB() const;
    void setIsConnectToDB(bool value);
    void run();

    void openConnToDB();

};

QSqlDatabase DbConnection::getDb() const
{
    return db;
}

void DbConnection::setDb(const QSqlDatabase &value)
{
    db = value;
}

bool DbConnection::getIsConnectToDB() const
{
    return isConnectToDB;
}

void DbConnection::setIsConnectToDB(bool value)
{
    isConnectToDB = value;
}

void DbConnection::run()
{
    openConnToDB();
    qDebug()<< "Open a connection from thread" << QThread::currentThread();
}

void DbConnection::openConnToDB() //=> work well in a simple test program
{

    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("test");
    db.setUserName("postgres");
    db.setPassword("1");
    db.setPort(5432);
    isConnectToDB = db.open("postgres","1");;
    //usleep(100000);
}


DbConnection::DbConnection()
{
}


class DBConnManager
{
private:
    DBConnManager();
    static DBConnManager *m_Instance;
    QThreadPool *threadPool;
    QList<DbConnection *> connList;
    DbConnection* conn;
public:

    static DBConnManager *getInstance();

    QList<DbConnection *> getConnList() const;
    void setConnList(const QList<DbConnection *> &value);
    QSqlDatabase acquireDb();
    DbConnection *getConn() const;
    void setConn(DbConnection *value);

    void closeDb();
};


DBConnManager *DBConnManager::m_Instance = 0;
DBConnManager::DBConnManager()
{
    threadPool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
}
DbConnection *DBConnManager::getConn() const
{
    return conn;
}

void DBConnManager::setConn(DbConnection *value)
{
    conn = value;
}

void DBConnManager::closeDb()
{
    if (conn==NULL) {
        qDebug()<< "NULL connection pointer";
        return;
    }

    conn->getDb().close();
}

QList<DbConnection *> DBConnManager::getConnList() const
{
    return connList;
}

void DBConnManager::setConnList(const QList<DbConnection *> &value)
{
    connList = value;
}

QSqlDatabase DBConnManager::acquireDb()
{
    conn = new DbConnection;
    connList.append(conn);
    threadPool->start(conn);

//    QSqlDatabase tmp;
//    return tmp;
    return conn->getDb();


}


DBConnManager *DBConnManager::getInstance()
{
    if (!m_Instance) {
        m_Instance = new DBConnManager;
    }

    return m_Instance;
}
```

and this is where it all begin:

```
QList<arcEntity> arcBL::getAll()
{
    QList <arcEntity> listResult;

    QSqlDatabase db = DBConnManager::getInstance()->acquireDb();

    bool result = m_arcDAL.getAll(&db,listResult);

    if (result==false) {
        qDebug()<<"Query get all fail";
    }
    DBConnManager::getInstance()->closeDb();
    return listResult;



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a number of things incorrectly.

Firstly, if you want more than one database connection simultaneously, you need to give them unique names.

From the documentation:

> **Warning**: If you add a connection with the same name as an existing connection, the new connection replaces the old one. If you call this function more than once without specifying connectionName, the default connection will be the one replaced.

You can choose whatever name you wish but an easy way I use to guarantee uniqueness is to use a name derived from an object's memory address, remembering to store the connection name so that it can be removed later, when the connection is no longer needed.

You could then modify your `openConnToDB()` function as such:

```
connectionName = QString("PSQL-%1").arg(reinterpret_cast<int>(this)); // store connection name
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL", connectionName);
```

You would then need to add a way to remove the connection once you're done with it.

```
void DbConnection::closeConnToDB() 
{
    if (db.isOpen())
        db.close();
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(connectionName);

}
```

---

Secondly, you don't have a full grasp of how to program multiple threads. Imagine reading the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    openConnToDB();
    qDebug()<< "Open a connection from thread" << QThread::currentThread();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm fairly sure that you'll see that the program doesn't do very much. The program begins execution by creating a database connection, it then creates a text message and then exits.

This is exactly what you've done with your secondary threads. You must treat `QRunnable::run()` or `QThread::run()` like your entry point function `main()`. As soon as the function exits, the thread can be thought of as being destroyed. (Footnote: With `QRunnable` and `QThreadPool` this isn't exactly what happens by for all practical purposes, it can be imagined to be so).

If you want your thread to stay alive, you need to keep the `run()` function from exiting. There are a number of ways to do this: you could use a `forever` loop, a `while` loop, or, if you want to process signals and slots in your thread like you would in your main thread,  you use an event loop.

```
MyRunnable::run()
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    // ...
    loop.exec();
}
```

You exit the event loop by connecting to the `QEventLoop::quit()` slot. (FYI: This is what happens inside the `QCoreApplication::exec()` function)

---

Thirdly, as @JKSH noted, you should not use SQL classes across thread boundaries.

This would mean that you should redesign your classes so that you don't have `DbConnection` class, but rather a `DBQuery` class. It's interface should allow you to pass a SQL query that needs to be executed and then results should be produced. Instances of `QSqlDatabase` and `QSqlQuery` should be kept private and internal, and be created only inside the `run()` function, or a function called from `run()`, in order to make sure they are in the worker thread.

One way to move SQL queries and results between threads is to use multiple inheritance with `QObject`:

```
class DBQuery: public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    // ...

public slots:
    void enqueueSQL(QString const &sql);


signals:
    void emitResults(QList<QVariant> const &records);

    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank for pointing it out :) Very informative :) Currently, I implement a `Worker` class sub-class `QThread` that works like your `DBQuery`. I will feedback again when it's done :)

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-modules.html) says this about Qt SQL: ***"A connection can only be used from within the thread that created it."*** You must open your database connection and execute all your queries in the same thread.

Usually, `QThreadPool` will use a different thread every time you run a `QRunnable`. This is not compatible with database access in Qt.

Use a `QThread` instead, in order to ensure that you use only 1 thread. Here is its documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html

Comment: Ok, I'll try to implement `QThread`. But I think when `DBConnManager::start(DbConnection*)` is called, it lives on another thread and all other functions it calls do live there as well?  So this error shouldn't occur:(